# <input type="file" accept="..."> の拡張子フィルタで、大文字小文字を区別する方法

Tags: windows, html5, google-chrome

htmlでファイルの投稿ボタンを以下のように作りました。

```
<form>
<input type="file" accept=".jpg"> 
...
</form>
```

windowsのgoogle-chromeでこのボタンを実行してファイル選択ダイアログを開くと、拡張子".jpg" と ".JPG" のファイルが表示されます。
この時、拡張子の大文字小文字を区別して、".jpg"のファイルだけを表示する方法はあるでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

残念ながら今のブラウザの仕様だとacceptに指定できる拡張子は大文字小文字区別なく表示することしかできなさそうです。OSによっては大文字小文字の区別ないですし。。

そもそも拡張子が大文字と小文字の違いでファイルには違いはないと思いますので、サーバ側で拡張子を小文字にファイルを保存し直してはどうでしょうか？

また、acceptはあくまでユーザヒントの機能でしかなく、実際はどのようなファイルも送信は可能なので結局小文字で制御したとしても、大文字の拡張子のファイルを送られたり、全く別のファイルが送られることはありますので制御は必要かと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。納得できました。